# What causes textures to be rendered on each triangle of a polygon?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am trying to render a textured square, but it looks like the texture doesn't get interpolated like it should. It looks like it gets mirrored on each triangle of my square. Behavior is presented on the image below.

Note that I'm using [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Combined_image_sampler) tutorial.

[image: As you can see, each triangle gets its own texture.]

I don't have an idea where to start fixing my code. Also, when I try to translate my Image layout, I get this error: `"Cannot submit cmd buffer using image 0x25 with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_BIT."`

Also, I get this warning when submitting a drawing command buffer for the first time: `"Cannot submit cmd buffer using image 0x25 with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL."`

Can this warning cause my issue? Also, here are my vertices and its texture coordinates.

```
vertices->setVertices({
{{-1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}},
{{1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}},
{{1.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}},
{{-1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}}
    });

vertices->setIndices({ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 });
```

**Update:**

Here is my image transition code:

```
void Util::transitionImageLayout(VkImage *image, VkFormat format, 
                                 VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout,
                                 VkCommandBuffer recordingBuffer) {
    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    VkImageSubresourceRange subresourceRange = {};
    VkPipelineStageFlags sourceStage = {};
    VkPipelineStageFlags dstStage = {};

    if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
        dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    }
    else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
        dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Layout transition not supported.");
    }

    subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;

    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.image = *image;
    barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
    barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
    barrier.subresourceRange = subresourceRange;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;  
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(recordingBuffer, sourceStage, dstStage, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, &barrier);
}
```

Here is my copy buffer to image code:

```
void Util::copyBufferToimage(VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer, VkBuffer buffer, 
                             VkImage *image, uint32_t width, uint32_t height) {
     VkBufferImageCopy region{};
     VkImageSubresourceLayers subresouce{};

     subresouce.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
     subresouce.baseArrayLayer = 0;
     subresouce.mipLevel = 0;
     subresouce.layerCount = 1;

     region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
     region.bufferOffset = 0;                                   
     region.bufferRowLength = 0;
     region.imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };                          
     region.imageExtent = { width, height, 1 };                 
     region.imageSubresource = subresouce;                      
     vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(cmdBuffer, buffer, *image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);
 }
```

**Notes:**
I have tried running the project from tutorial's git repo, and it works fine. They get no warnings.

Comment: Can you change `vertices->setIndices({ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 });` to  `vertices->setIndices({ 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 });` and test it again? (edited)

Comment: About that warning, images start with layout undefined you need to transition from undefined to transferDst. Make sure src and dst are what you want them to be.

Comment: Setting indices results in rendering only a triangle, because render mode is set to triangle list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my vertices struct code which I didn't provide. Format of texture coordinates was wrong. It should be `R32 G32`, and I have set it to `R32 G32 B32 A32`.

```
static std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> getAttributeDescriptions() {
    std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> attributeDescriptions = {};

    attributeDescriptions[0].binding = 0;                           
    attributeDescriptions[0].location = 0;                          
    attributeDescriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
    attributeDescriptions[0].offset = offsetof(Vertex, position);

    attributeDescriptions[1].binding = 0;
    attributeDescriptions[1].location = 1;
    attributeDescriptions[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    attributeDescriptions[1].offset = offsetof(Vertex, color);

    attributeDescriptions[2].binding = 0;
    attributeDescriptions[2].location = 2;
    attributeDescriptions[2].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT;      //This is an error. I guess this has to do something with texCoord being a glm::vec2
    attributeDescriptions[2].offset = offsetof(Vertex, texCoord);

    return attributeDescriptions;
}
```

So, attributes descriptions format regarding the texture coordinates should be

```
attributeDescriptions[2].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
```

Now my polygon looks like this:

[image]